# Twitter Bootstrap Rails: How to write semantic HTML by reusing classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, less, twitter-bootstrap-rails

So I installed the [`twitter-bootstrap-rails`](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) gem. I ran the generator to create a `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less` file. Now I would like to write some semantic HTML. So instead of writing:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span2">Column1</div>
    <div class="span6">Column2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to write:

```
<div id="foo-wrapper">
  <div class="foo">
    <div class="foo-left">Column1</div>
    <div class="foo-right">Column2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, when I try to write the less for this, the classes are not applied:

```
// at the bottom of bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less
#foo-wrapper {
  .container;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this not supported? Am I defining my styles in the wrong place? Am I using the wrong gem for working with Twitter Bootstrap?

### Update:

Here is the comment in the `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less`:

```
// Your custom LESS stylesheets goes here
//
// Since bootstrap was imported above you have access to its mixins which
// you may use and inherit here
```

For some reason, it doesn't seem like I have access to the mixins and I don't understand why.

Comment: I'm insterested in something like this because I thought to do something very similar but using SASS' Selector Inheritance (with `@extend`) I'm wondering if it was a good idea because of a similar behaviour when I tried (CSS' rules was overridden somehow and then nothing happened). Are the `#foo-wrapper`'s rules overridden in Firebug?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want a SASS feature named "selector inheritance"

It lets you extend a class with another class

```
.bordered {      
  border: 1px solid back; 
} 
#menu a {                   
  @extend .bordered;      
}
```

Would produce:

```
.bordered, #menu a {
border: 1px solid back; }
```

[Comparison of LESS and SASS](https://gist.github.com/674726)

So you could move to a sass implementation of bootstrap, and then do exactly what you want. https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass)

Answer (score 2):

You should double check Bootstrap's [mixins](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/less.html#mixins). Instead you'll want something like

```
#container {
    .center-block();
}

.foo-wrapper {
    .makeRow();
}

.foo-left {
    .makeColumn(8,0);
}

.foo-right {
    .makeColumn(4,0);
}
```

which the mixins to fill in those special Bootstrap classes.

Comment: Ah, this makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass with Compass
and it works fine.

just like @Jesse Wolgamott said, the "selector inheritance" feature!

or you could check this out:
[How to reuse a class in sass without using a mixin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400219/how-to-reuse-a-class-in-sass-without-using-a-mixin)

and this issue is common when reusing span*:
[How to use twitter bootstrap with bootstrap-sass in rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897728/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-with-bootstrap-sass-in-rails-app)