# How to reuse a class in sass without using a mixin?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I want all my anchors in my application look like .btn (Twitter Bootstrap class), is there a way to make this?

I did

```
a{
  @include btn;
}
```

but it does not work because btn should be a mixin, and it's a Twitter Bootstrap class.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You want to use `@extend .btn;` - @extend allows you to inherit all the properties of a selector without having to define it as a mixin.

Comment: I made a{@extend .btn;} and the compiled css does not have any a{}, what could be happening?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the contents of your main application CSS? Mainly I want to see the the `//=require` directives, or the `@import` commands if you're using that.

Comment: What are the advatages of not using a mixin?

Comment: `@extend` can't be used inside of a media query. If I want to use a class from an external library, like materialize, within a media query, `@extend` is not an option, and neither is going into the library code and changing the class declaration into a mixin declaration. Is there no option in this circumstance? Other preprocessors are fine using normal classes as if they were mixins.

Answer (score 20):

This is exactly what you want => https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass

1. Install the gem `bootstrap-sass`
2. In `config.rb` => `require 'bootstrap-sass'`
3. `@import "bootstrap";` at the top of your scss file.

To use write

```
a {
  @extend .btn;
}
```

Comment: I'd already bootstrap-sass installed