# Bootstrap only for mixins/placeholders - with semantic classes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, compass-sass

I'm thinking about using only semantic classes in my HTML, while still using Bootstrap's classes styles inside the semantic classes.

For example:

mixins:

```
.newsItem {
    @include span4;
}
```

or placeholders/extends:

```
.newsItem {
    extend span4;
}
```

Is it possible at all? and do you see any reason why that's not recommended ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@include span4;` and `@extend .span4;` won't work because:

- In the first one, there isn't any mixins called that way in bootstrap.
- In the second one, there isn't any selector called `span4`, the selectors are being generated with mixins like `grid-core-span-x`.

There are built mixins for that purpose: `makeRow()` and `makeColumn()`.

In your case, if you want to use a `span4` in your `.newsItem` div, you have to put this in your SASS:

```
.newsItem {
  @include makeColumn(4);
}
```

The code from those mixins is simple.

```
@mixin makeRow() {
  margin-left: $gridGutterWidth * -1;
  @include clearfix();
}

@mixin makeColumn($columns: 1, $offset: 0) {
  float: left;
  margin-left: ($gridColumnWidth * $offset) + ($gridGutterWidth * ($offset - 1)) + ($gridGutterWidth * 2);
  width: ($gridColumnWidth * $columns) + ($gridGutterWidth * ($columns - 1));
}
```

This mixins have **downsides**. I don't use them since the responsive grid won't be used in your semantics class. Why? Because if you look at the files that provide bootstrap a responsive (for instance, `_responsive-767px-max.scss`), only the `spanX` classes converts to a 100% width. The code:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) { 
     /* ... */

     [class*="span"],
     .uneditable-input[class*="span"], 
     .row-fluid [class*="span"] {
         float: none;
         display: block;
         width: 100%;
         margin-left: 0;
         @include box-sizing(border-box);

      /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Is that true only for the grid? what If for example, I want to use a semantic button class ?

Comment: @Daniel You can use `@extend` for some components of bootstrap. Button class is one of them because the CSS from the button is simple, it hasn't nested selectors. But for example, you shouldn't reuse `form-horizontal`, because the generated CSS will be horrible, because of the nested selectors.

Comment: @Daniel I have an example in this answer with the button override: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16406593/1004046