# Twitter Bootstrap witih Saas MakeFluidColumn mixin is missing - trying to not hardcode span into a class in HTML

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm using Thomas Macdonald's sass version of bootstrap (bootstrap-sass)

I'm trying to not embed Bootstrap classes (i.e. span7 or span10) in my html as described in here.
http://ruby.bvision.com/blog/please-stop-embedding-bootstrap-classes-in-your-html

in bootstrap-sass the only sass mixin that I know is available to apply the "span7" class to my div is with `@include makeColumn(7);`

This works for fixed grid but not for a fluid grid.  I need these columns to be fluid and responsive.
@Thomas Macdonald answered the question on StackOverflow with a mix-in that he created called makeFluidColumn 
[How to use twitter bootstrap with bootstrap-sass in rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897728/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-with-bootstrap-sass-in-rails-app/9909626#9909626)

but it is not included anymore in the latest mixin file as is also mentioned per this github issue:
https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/issues/191

Is there something else that I need to do?  I need to be able to change the span as a mixin because I am trying to change the number of columns that a div spans depending on viewport size through media queries.

Comment: Writing your own mixin is always a possibility.  Just because you're using TB doesn't mean you can't mix and match with other libraries out there.  Susy (http://susy.oddbird.net/demos/grid-types/) is fairly popular and can be fixed or fluid (not a grid user myself, so I can't comment on how well it does the job).

Comment: I decided to not go with a grid also with this part. just calculating the div width percentage based on a 12 column grid.  I would like to avoid mixing in too many dependencies so would love it if I could just use the TWB grid or not at all.  If anyone can suggest a way to do makeFluidColumn mix-in that works in Sass, that'd be really awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rolling my own @mixin.

so instead of using bootstrap's @include makeColumn(i); i can do @include col(i) to apply a width of i number of columns to a div or other element.  Just include this SCSS file

```
    /*=VARIABLES - GRID
------------------------------------------------*/
$columns: $gridColumns; //from bootstrap/_variables.scss
$column-width: $gridColumnWidth; //from bootstrap/_variables.scss
$gutter-width: $gridGutterWidth; //from bootstrap/_variables.scss
$max-width: $columns * ($column-width + $gutter-width);


/*=VARIABLES - FONTS
------------------------------------------------*/
$font-base: $baseFontSize; //from bootstrap/_variables.scss
$font-base-line-height: $baseLineHeight; //from bootstrap/_variables.scss
$font-base-line-height-half: $font-base-line-height / 2;
$font-base-percentage: (($font-base / 16px) * 100) + 0%;


/*MIXINS
------------------------------------------------*/
@mixin col($n, $padding: 0px, $border: 0px, $container-width: $max-width) {
    float: left;
    margin-left: percentage($gutter-width / $container-width);
    width: percentage(($n * ($column-width + $gutter-width) - $gutter-width - ($padding * 2) - ($border * 2)) / $container-width);
    border-width: $border;
    padding: em($padding, $font-base) percentage($padding / $container-width);
}

/*FUNCTIONS
------------------------------------------------*/
@function em($target, $context: $font-base) {
    @if $target == 0 { @return 0 }
    @return $target / $context + 0em;
}

@function perc($width, $container-width: $max-width) {
    @return percentage($width / $container-width);
}

@function lh($amount: 1, $context: $font-base) {
    @return em($font-base-line-height * $amount, $context);
}

@function heading-line-height($size) {

    $line-height: $font-base-line-height;

    $match: false;
    @while $match != true {

        @if $size == $line-height {
            $match: true;
        } @else if  $size < $line-height {
            $match: true;
        } @else if $size > $line-height {
            $line-height: $line-height + $font-base-line-height;
        } @else {
            $match: true;
        }

    } 

    @return ($line-height / $size) + 0em;
}
```