# Semantic Grid with Bootstrap + LESS Mixins ¿ HOW?

Tags: css, twitter, twitter-bootstrap, less, mixins

Twitter bootstrap documentation talks about three mixins to generate grid systems:

```
.container-fixed();
#grid > .core();
#grid > .fluid();
```

I know how to setup the page to use bootstrap and less... But I don't know how to use the grid system semantically. The documentation says what mixins to use but not how... ¿ Could anyone ilustrate how to use them in order to create semantic grids ? Just to figure out or to see how it works :S

Thank you !!

Comment: This worked for me:

[Another Stackoverflow answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090238/tweaking-bootstrap-2-0-for-semantic-markup

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In navbar.less of bootstrap you will find the following.

## grid and .core are used to namespace the .span()

```
.navbar-fixed-top .container,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
#grid > .core > .span(@gridColumns);
}
```

In cases where you want to keep "span3" etc out of your html you could very well do something similar to:

```
header {
   #grid > .core .span(12)
}

article.right {
   #grid > .core .span(6)
}

aside.right {
   #grid > .core .span(6)
}

footer {
   #grid > .core .span(12)
}
```

(12) and (6) are the number of columns you'd like your header element to span. This is of course replacing

```
<header class="span12"></header>
<article class="span6"></article>
<aside class="span6"></aside>
<footer class="span12"></footer>
```

Comment: so this is basically doing what http://semantic.gs/ does - but with the advantage of letting you choose which way you do it